# Streaming data from the database - ASP.NET Core & SqlDataReader.GetStream()

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, streaming, sqldatareader

I'm trying to minimize loading large objects into memory from the database when sending them out from an ASP.NET Core site because I'm hitting `OutOfMemoryException` on occasion.

I figured I'd stream it. Now from my research SQL Server supports this so long as you've specified `CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess` in your command. I figured if I'm going to stream it, I might as well stream it as directly as possible, so I'm pretty much streaming it directly from the `DataReader` to the ASP.NET MVC `ActionResult`.

But once the `FileStreamResult` (hidden under the call to `File()`) has finished executing, how do I clean up my reader/command? The connection was provided by DI, so that's not a problem, but I create the reader/command in the call to `GetDocumentStream()`.

I have a subclass of `ActionFilterAttribute` registered in MVC, so that gives me an entry point I can call for `ActionFilterAttribute.OnResultExecuted()`, but I have absolutely no idea on what to put there other than my current logic that deals with cleaning up my database transaction and commit/rollback stuff (not included since it's not really relevant).

Is there a way to cleanup after my `DataReader`/`Command` and still provide a `Stream` to `File()`?

```cs
public class DocumentsController : Controller
{
    private DocumentService documentService;

    public FilesController(DocumentService documentService)
    {
        this.documentService = documentService;
    }

    public IActionResult Stream(Guid id, string contentType = "application/octet-stream") // Defaults to octet-stream when unspecified
    {
        // Simple lookup by Id so that I can use it for the Name and ContentType below
        if(!(documentService.GetDocument(id)) is Document document) 
            return NotFound();

        var cd = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("inline") {FileNameStar = document.DocumentName};
        Response.Headers.Add(Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderNames.ContentDisposition, cd.ToString());

        return File(documentService.GetDocumentStream(id), document.ContentType ?? contentType);
    }

    /*
    public class Document
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string DocumentName { get; set; }
        public string ContentType { get; set; }
    }
    */
}

public class DocumentService
{
    private readonly DbConnection connection;

    public DocumentService(DbConnection connection)
    {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    /* Other content omitted for brevity */

    public Stream GetDocumentStream(Guid documentId)
    {
        //Source table definition
        /*
            CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblDocuments]
            (
                [DocumentId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
                [ContentType] [varchar](100) NULL,
                [DocumentName] [varchar](100) NULL,
                [DocumentData] [varbinary](max) NULL
            CONSTRAINT [PK_DocumentId] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([DocumentID] ASC)
            )
            GO
         */

        const string query = "SELECT DocumentData FROM tblDocuments WHERE DocumentId = @documentId";

        //build up the command
        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = query;
        var parameter = command.CreateParameter();
        parameter.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Guid;
        parameter.ParameterName = "@documentId";
        parameter.Value = documentId;
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

        //Execute commmand with SequentialAccess to support streaming the data
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);

        if(reader.Read())
            return reader.GetStream(0);
        else
            return Stream.Null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you consider using [IAsyncEnumerable<T>](https://anthonychu.ca/post/async-streams-dotnet-core-3-iasyncenumerable/) (requires .NET Core 3.0 though). It was made specificially to support async enumeration of data, like in this case

Comment: Other than that, use the `using` pattern for resources you allocated by yourself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I worked my way though all of @Tseng's suggestions, simple ones first, ending with the more involved one. Ultimately I couldn't use the method of registering an object to be disposed for me, because it happens too late in the process and I am cleaning up my database transaction in the `OnResultExecuted` method of my `ActionFilter`. So I went for the custom `ActionResult` class.

The `StreamableDisposable` (and its interface) are just to simplify the fact that I need to return two things, the stream and the datareader, and didn't want to expose the reader's underlying `GetStream(0)` method by only returning the reader.

```
public interface IStreamableDisposible : IDisposable
{
    public System.IO.Stream Stream { get; }
}
```

```
public class StreamableDisposible : IStreamableDisposible
{
    private readonly IDisposable toDisposeOf;

    public StreamableDisposible(System.IO.Stream stream, System.Data.Common.DbDataReader toDisposeOf)
    {
        Stream = stream ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(stream));
        this.toDisposeOf = toDisposeOf;
    }

    public System.IO.Stream Stream { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        toDisposeOf?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This is the new `ActionResult` class so that I can ensure that my disposable is cleaned up immediately after the stream is finished being used to execute the result.

```
public class DisposingFileStreamResult : FileStreamResult
{
    private readonly IStreamableDisposible streamableDisposible;

    public DisposingFileStreamResult(IStreamableDisposible streamableDisposible, string contentType)
        : base(streamableDisposible.Stream, contentType)
    {
        this.streamableDisposible = streamableDisposible ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(streamableDisposible));
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ActionContext context)
    {
        base.ExecuteResult(context);
        streamableDisposible.Dispose();
    }

    public override Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        return base.ExecuteResultAsync(context).ContinueWith(x => streamableDisposible.Dispose());
    }
}
```

This let me update my `GetDocumentStream()` method to be as follows

```
public StreamableDisposible GetDatabaseStream(Guid documentId)
{
    const string query = "SELECT DocumentData FROM tblDocuments WHERE DocumentId = @documentId AND DocumentData IS NOT NULL AND DATALENGTH(DocumentData) > 0";
    using var command = ((NHibernateData)Data).ManualCommand();

    command.CommandText = query;
    var parameter = command.CreateParameter();
    parameter.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Guid;
    parameter.ParameterName = "@documentId";
    parameter.Value = documentId;
    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

    //Execute commmand with SequentialAccess to support streaming the data
    var reader = command.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);
    if(reader.Read())
        return new StreamableDisposible(reader.GetStream(0), reader);
    else
    {
        reader.Dispose();
        return null;
    }
}
```

And my action now looks like this

```
public IActionResult Stream(Guid id, string contentType = "application/octet-stream") // Defaults to octet-stream when unspecified
{
    // Simple lookup by Id so that I can use it for the Name and ContentType below
    if(!(documentService.GetDocument(id)) is Document document) 
        return NotFound();

    var cd = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("inline") {FileNameStar = document.DocumentName};
    Response.Headers.Add(Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderNames.ContentDisposition, cd.ToString());

    var sd = var sd = documentService.GetDocumentStream(id);
    return new DisposingFileStreamResult(sd, document.ContentType ?? contentType);
}
```

I added checks to the SELECT statement to account for null data columns, or just null data length to eliminate having to have checks for the both `StreamableDisposable` and for the `Stream` itself being null, or just possibly no data, etc.

This is pretty much all of the code I ended up using.

Answer (score 3):

After posting the comment I also remembered that there's an rarely used API.

You can register any disposable classes to be disposed at the end of the request (when the response has been written):

```
HttpContext.Response.RegisterForDispose(reader);
```

Alternatively hook into the `OnCompleted` response callback and do your cleanups there (i.e. if objects are not disposable or if you need to call special methods as part of the clean up)

```
HttpContext.Response.OnCompleted(() =>
{
    reader.Dispose();
    return Task.CompletedTask;
});
```

Last but not least, if done in a lot of methods, having your own `SqlSequencialStreamingResult` class may be your best choice

Comment: I didn't know about the `RegisterForDispose`, that's interesting. The OnComplete seems like an interesting fallback but doesn't feel as clean.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of the idea of creating my own `SqlSequencialStreamingResult` as I was falling alseep last night . Then I could register the dispose of the command/reader within the dispose of the custom `ActionResult`

Comment: Ha, the definition of `RegisterForDispose`, it just adds a delegate to `OnCompleted`. So it's the same thing just cleaner syntax

Comment: `RegisterForDispose` -> Cleaner syntax for one, but more importantly its easier discoverable via auto completition when it says `RegisterForDispose` you know what its for but its not obvious when you have to do `HttpContext.Response.OnCompleted(...)` that you can dispose in there too

Comment: Seems like `RegisterForDispose` doesn't fire until the very end, so it's not executed before I try to clean up my transaction in my `ActionFilterAttribute`. I had to go the route of a custom `ActionResult`. I'll post my code for that once I get it all working 100%